# Framework7 Loop Dynamic Content within Route

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, html-framework-7

I am using Framework 7 to load demo cards in the router.  The problem is I am not sure how to loop through multiple records in the template display.

Here is my route

```
{
path: '/about/',
async: function (routeTo, routeFrom, resolve, reject) {
  // Requested route
  // Get external data and return template7 template
  app.request.json('data.json', function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    resolve(
      // How and what to load: template
      {
        template: `<div class="page">
                    <div class="navbar">
                        <div class="navbar-inner sliding">
                          <div class="left">
                            <a href="#" class="link back">
                              <i class="icon icon-back"></i>
                              <span class="ios-only">Back</span>
                            </a>
                          </div>
                          <div class="title">News</div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="page-content">
                        <div class="card demo-card-header-pic">
                              <div style="background-image:url({{TitleImg}})" class="card-header align-items-flex-end"></div>
                              <div class="card-content card-content-padding">
                                <p class="date">{{Title}}</p>
                                <p>{{Header}}</p>
                              </div>
                              <div class="card-footer"><a href="/about/3/" class="link">Read more</a></div>
                            </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>`
      },
      // Custom template context
      {
        context: {
          ID: data.content.ID,
            Title: data.content.Title,
            Header: data.content.Header,
            Description: data.content.Description,
            TitleImg: data.content.TitleImg,
        },
      }
    );
  });
}
```

},

here is sample json:

```
{
"contentType": "news",
"content": [{
    "ID": 1,
    "Title": "Test",
    "Header": "Short Text",
    "Description": "lorem ipsum",
    "TitleImg": "/img/collab.jpg"
}, {
    "ID": 2,
    "Title": "Test2",
    "Header": "Short Text2",
    "Description": "lorem ipsum2",
    "TitleImg": "/img/collab.jpg"
}]
```

}

Right now it doesn't show anything but I would like to see both entries.

TAKE 2 but still not working.... the items array has my data but the for loop doesnt work

```
{
path: '/about/',
async: function (routeTo, routeFrom, resolve, reject) {
  // Requested route
  // Get external data and return template7 template
  app.request.json('data.json', function (data) {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.content.length; i++) {
          items.push({
            ID: data.content[i].ID,
            TitleImg: data.content[i].TitleImg,
            Title: data.content[i].Title,
            Header: data.content[i].Header
          });
        }
      console.log(items);
    resolve(
      {
        template: `<div class="page">
                    <div class="navbar">
                        <div class="navbar-inner sliding">
                          <div class="left">
                            <a href="#" class="link back">
                              <i class="icon icon-back"></i>
                              <span class="ios-only">Back</span>
                            </a>
                          </div>
                          <div class="title">News</div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="page-content">
                        <div class="card demo-card-header-pic" v-for="item in items">
                              <div style="background-image:url({{TitleImg}})" class="card-header align-items-flex-end"></div>
                              <div class="card-content card-content-padding">
                                <p class="date">{{Title}}</p>
                                <p>{{Header}}</p>
                              </div>
                              <div class="card-footer"><a href="/about/{{ID}}/" class="link">Read more</a></div>
                            </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>`
      },
      {
        items: items,
      }
    );
  });
}
```

},

EDIT - Working solution thanks @djiggy

```
{{#each items}}
                        <div class="card demo-card-header-pic">
                            <a href="/about/{{ID}}/">
                              <div style="background-image:url({{TitleImg}})" class="card-header align-items-flex-end"><div class="card-headerTxt">{{Title}}</div></div>
                              <div class="card-content card-content-padding">
                                <p>{{Header}}</p>
                              </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        {{/each}}
```

Comment: can you log `data.content[i]` ?

Comment: data.content[i] logs correct.  the items array gets built how I would like... I believe the problem is in the template. I am just not sure of the syntax to look through each item.

Comment: Oh ! change `{items: items}` to   `{ context: { items: items }}` and let me know if it's working

Comment: @Djiggy That did not change anything :(

Comment: Try to replace `v-for` attr by Template7 `each` (`{{#each items}}`) and use `{{this.wathever}}`

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Comment: This link was also helpful - https://muut.com/framework7#!/framework7/questions:template7-each-

Comment: Perfect ! I'll write an answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use data as Template7, you have to use Template7 syntax (cf. [expressions syntax section](http://idangero.us/template7/))

So in your case, you have to update `v-for` to `each` block

Useful link : [Access to object with each](https://muut.com/framework7#!/framework7/questions:template7-each-)